# $or query in Mongo with GeoJSON

Tags: mongodb, geojson

I would like to build a query in Mongo that will return either documents within a certain proximity of a geographic point or documents that match another query criteria. This is how my query looks now:

```
{
  "$or":[
    {"status":"Friend"},
    {
      "location":{
        "$near":{
          "$geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[-86.4181,35.871]
          },
          "$maxDistance":32186.8
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I try this query, I get the following error:

```
MongoError: exception: geoNear must be top-level expr
```

Looking at the Mongo docs, it appears I can only perform searches that return results within a proximity AND the other criteria.

Is this the case, or is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported, see [SERVER-13974](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13974). Your best bet would be to run 2 separate queries.